# rails server not working, Rails 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm following the Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl and after i bundle install all the required gems the rails server gives me an error when i run it. Im using Windows

here's the error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/slave.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/slave.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console.rb:13:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `<top(required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
 from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
    from C:/sites/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top(required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'

 from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'

from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

here is the Gemfile:

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.23.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
end
```

all help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error it seems the `web-console` gem in your dev group is causing the issue. Some looking around [online](https://github.com/rails/web-console/issues/19) and it appears that this particular gem does not work well in a Windows environment (Arguably, Rails as a whole does not cooperate on a Windows machine).

Try commenting out `web-console` and then `bundle install`, `rails c`

If still no luck add:

`gem 'rubysl-pty', :platforms => :ruby`

`gem 'web-console', :platforms => :ruby`

then `bundle install`, `rails c` and let us know if that resolves your problem!

Alternatively, I would recommend using [cloud9](https://c9.io/) or if you want to work locally on a rails app, and are using a Windows machine, try installing Linux/Unix...

Comment: I tried adding and commenting the gems, but still got the some other errors

Comment: Can you add what those new errors are? If possible, one set with ONLY `web-console` commented out, and another set with `web-console` edited out & those two gems added. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!, the new error was about tzinfo-data and i just pasted back the 'gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]' back at the gemfile and both rails server and rails console are now running without erros

Comment: Excellent! Can you let us know which of the suggested gems I mentioned are currently being used on your system? I suspect just commenting out the `web-console` will do the trick, but would be good to know in case someone comes by this question. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using both  gem 'rubysl-pty', :platforms => :ruby and gem 'web-console', :platforms => :ruby. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
```

to

```
gem 'web-console', '>= 2.0.0'
```

should make it work